# ubuntu upstart not respawning the daemon despite respawn in the config file

Tags: upstart

I have problems with my deamon restart. upstart is not spawning the daemon when the daemon crashes.
here is my upstart init file .
pls advise.

```
description "bezkon watch dog"



start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel  [!2345]

respawn

expect fork

script

        logger -s "Bezkon watch dog booting ..."

        logger -s "Waiting for engine to complete booting sleeping for 60 seconds "

        sleep 300

        export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

        export LUA_PATH=$LUA_PATH:/usr/local/bezkon/

        export LUA_CPATH=$LUA_CPATH:/usr/local/bezkon/

        chdir /usr/local/bezkon;

end script

exec /usr/local/bezkon/bezkon_dog >> /var/log/bezkon_crash.log 2>&1
```

Comment: What system calls are you using to daemonize in the watchdog program?

Comment: I am using the daemon system call to daemonize the process.

Comment: What's the output of `initctl status` when you kill the daemon? Before?

Comment: what is this thing , i am not aware of this ? can you give some detail ?

Comment: Sorry. `initctl` is the program you are actually using when you run `start [job]` (`initctl start [job]`). `initctl status [job]` should give you the "state" of the job as Upstart sees it, along with the process ID it is tracking. The PID could tell us whether it's actually tracking the right process.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use `script` and `exec` together. Try `pre-start script` instead. Or put the exec line inside the script stanza. Not sure how this works together with `expect fork` though.

**EDIT**: Take a look at [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/406397) by Scott Remnant, the lead Upstart dev. It looks like it would apply to your config file, and it doesn't appear that it has been fixed yet. I still think you might want to try `pre-start script`, or experiment with `expect daemon` vs. `expect fork` vs. nothing. Assuming you haven't done this already, it can't hurt.

Comment: but this script works now and upstart seems to be happy with this.

Comment: And you're sure your daemon is starting in the first place? If so, what happens when it dies? Any log messages, either in your `bezkon_crash.log` or in the syslog?

Comment: i am killing it with kill command and i expect the upstart to restart my daemon. yes my daemon is starting. bezkon_crash.log is just for capturing the stack trace when the daemon crashes. the daemon is written in LUA

Comment: Okay. I know next to nothing about LUA, so I'm sorry for fumbling around in the dark here. How is your daemon set up to fork? I take it you've checked it without `expect fork` and it doesn't work?

Comment: Forget that. Saw your other comment.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Tim , seems i can mine some useful from the mail thread.

Comment: It seems some problem with the way i daemonize the processes. I wrote a simple test program in c using the daemon system call to deamonize the process. it seems to work and it gets respawned when i kill the process. still debugging whats wrong with the lua thing.